# How to use elasticsearch calculate growth rate

Tags: database, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using `Elasticsearch` and `Grafana` to show stock growth, ex,
`(price[i]-price[first])/price[first]` just like growth rate,
but i don't know how to query

here is the sample data

```
PUT stock/_doc/1
{
    "Code": "0000666",
    "Name": "test",
    "Price": 0.665,
    "Date": "2020-01-01"
}

PUT stock/_doc/2
{
    "Code": "0000666",
    "Name": "test",
    "Price": 0.670,
    "Date": "2020-01-02"
}

PUT stock/_doc/3
{
    "Code": "0000666",
    "Name": "test",
    "Price": 0.685,
    "Date": "2020-01-03"
}

PUT stock/_doc/4
{
    "Code": "0000666",
    "Name": "test",
    "Price": 0.690,
    "Date": "2020-01-04"
}

PUT stock/_doc/5
{
    "Code": "0000666",
    "Name": "test",
    "Price": 0.692,
    "Date": "2020-01-05"
}
```

I used `painless` ,but it only use on single doc

I used `derivative`,but it only use on two doc,not the first doc

Comment: can you post the sample data?

Comment: just updated,thanks